# angular ng-options select filter ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options, angular-filters

I am rewriting an angular select option, previously I was using a bootstrap btn-group class with numerous li classes, which used ng-click to set a filter in my ng-repeat list which worked perfectly. Like so:

```
<li role="menuitem">
   <a ng-click="myFilter = { moving: true }">Delivery &amp; Removals</a>
</li>
```

However, after some feedback, I have been asked to change it to a `<select>` with `<option>` set up, so to reflect the selected option.

I have added a list to my controller scope, like so:

```
$scope.taskCategories = [
    {'cat': 'Moving & Delivery', 'filter': 'moving: true'},
    {'cat': 'DIY', 'filter': 'DIY: true'},
    {'cat': 'Marketing', 'filter': 'marketing: true' }
]
```

Here is the select

```
{{ selectedCat.filter }}
<select ng-model="selectedCat" ng-value="x.filter" ng-options="x.cat for x in taskCategories">
  </select>
```

Here is my ng-repeat

```
data-ng-repeat="task in vm.tasks | filter:search | filter:myFilter | filter: { filter: selectedCat.filter } : true | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:x as results"
```

To give a bit of relevance, my ng-click filters work like so:

```
ng-click="myFilter = { moving: true }"
```

However, when I click on one of my select values, which are ng-repeating through the $scope.taskCategories just fine, my ng-repeat returns 0 results, which is not correct.

If anyone could give me any pointers on where I am going wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle.

Comment: @NNR thanks very much for your quick response, I have tried to replicate the issue here: http://plnkr.co/S1gC8KtmZ1akp58PJa1e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom filter and search by the property inside the object, as the following:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('ngRepeat', ['ngAnimate'])
.controller('repeatController', function($scope) {
  $scope.tasks = [
     {
        'created': "2016-07-02T21:01:56.095Z",
        'description':"hang it",
        'dueDate':"2016-07-02T22:00:00.000Z",
        'inPersonTask':true,
        'isCurrentUserOwner':false,
        'moving':true,
        'profileImageURL':"modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png",
        'statusAssigned':false,
        'statusClosed':false,
        'statusOpen':true,
        'taskLocation':"eerywhere",
        'title':'example 3'
        },
        {
        'created': "2016-07-02T21:01:56.095Z",
        'description':"hang it",
        'dueDate':"2016-07-02T22:00:00.000Z",
        'inPersonTask':true,
        'isCurrentUserOwner':false,
        'DIY':true,
        'profileImageURL':"modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png",
        'statusAssigned':false,
        'statusClosed':false,
        'statusOpen':true,
        'taskLocation':"the world",
        'title':'example 2'
        },
        {
        'created': "2016-07-02T21:01:56.095Z",
        'description':"hang it",
        'dueDate':"2016-07-02T22:00:00.000Z",
        'inPersonTask':true,
        'isCurrentUserOwner':false,
        'marketing':true,
        'profileImageURL':"modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png",
        'statusAssigned':false,
        'statusClosed':false,
        'statusOpen':true,
        'taskLocation':"the world",
        'title':'example 3'
        }
  ];
  $scope.taskCategories = [
        {'cat': 'Moving & Delivery', 'filter': 'moving: true'},
        {'cat': 'DIY', 'filter': 'DIY: true'},
        {'cat': 'Marketing', 'filter': 'marketing: true' }
    ];
})

  .filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function(items, search) {
      if (!search) {
        return items;
      }    

      return items.filter(function(element) {
       // Ex: moving: true, becomes just 'moving'
       return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(element).find(x => x == search.substring(0, search.indexOf(':')));
      });
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```

```css
.example-animate-container {
  background:white;
  border:1px solid black;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0 10px;
}

.animate-repeat {
  line-height:30px;
  list-style:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-move,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter,
.animate-repeat.ng-leave {
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.animate-repeat.ng-move,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter {
  opacity:0;
  max-height:0;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-leave,
.animate-repeat.ng-move.ng-move-active,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
  max-height:30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <link href="animations.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="ngRepeat">
  <div ng-controller="repeatController">
    <!-- list of tasks /-->
    <h3>List of tasks, without filter</h3>
    <ul class="example-animate-container">
      <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="task in tasks">[{{$index + 1}}] {{ task.title }}, {{ task.taskLocation }}</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- list of tasks with filter /-->
    <h3>List of tasks with filter -- results are not showing</h3>
    <p>{{ selectedCat }}</p>
    <select ng-model="selectedCat" ng-options="x.cat for x in taskCategories" ng-value="x.filter">
    </select>
    <ul>
      <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="task in tasks | customFilter: selectedCat.filter">
        [{{$index + 1}}] {{ task.title }}, {{ task.taskLocation }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your assistance, I will try this out now and let you know how I get on asap :)

Comment: You can check the snippet above.

Comment: Sorry, I just needed to test locally. Thanks so much! worked like a charm. I have marked as accepted answer. Thanks again!

Comment: sorry to bug you again - I am getting an error with the => arrow function, how would you recommend rewriting find(x => x == search.substring(0, search.indexOf(':'))); ? many thanks again!

Comment: Hmm.. you're compilling your **JS** files, right? To change is simple: `return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(element).find(function(x) { return x == search.substring(0, search.indexOf(':')) });`